# When editing a text input, how do I do a specific JavaScript action on hitting "Enter" key without the form's onSubmit handler?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML `input` text field.

How can I perform a specific JavaScript call when hitting "Enter" button while editing that field? Currently, hitting "Enter" reloads the entire page, presumably due to submitting the entire form.

NOTE: This HTML/JS code is merely included as a portlet into a large HTML page for a portal, which has one large master form wrapped all the way around my code. Therefore **I can not control the form - can't change onSubmit event or action or wrap my `INPUT` field into a smaller form** - otherwise the solution would be obvious :)

Also, a solution that does not involve adding a *visible* button to the form is *strongly* preferable (I don't mind adding a button with `display:hidden` if that's what it takes, but my attempt to do so didn't seem to work).

This needs to be straight up JS - no Query/Prototype/YUI is available.

P.S. it's a search field and the action will be a call to an existing in-page JavaScript search method, if someone's curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a text input something like

```
<input id="myTextBox" name="foo" value="bar">
```

... you could do something like this, after the document has loaded, and it will work in all mainstream browsers:

```
document.getElementById("myTextBox").onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    if (charCode == 13) {
        // Suppress default action of the keypress
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        evt.returnValue = false;

        // Do stuff here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the following javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function noenter() {
    return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); 
}
</script>
```

Add the following attribute into the input element that you wish to prevent the submit

```
onkeypress="return noenter()"
```

Of course you can perform some other event if you wish...

Comment: +1 - This worked perfectly in initial testing - Thanks! If no better solution (aesthetics wise) is presented in 2 days I'll accept this (nothing personal, I just really hate capturing keyclicks like this :)

Comment: I do not take it personally.  If there is a better solution, I would like to see it too, because ultimately, usability is what you are after.

Comment: This don't works in Firefox, for Firefox you need use var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which, then test keyCode var.

Comment: This will not work in browsers other than IE, for two reasons: first the one that Cesar mentioned, and second that only IE refers to the event as `window.event`. See my answer for a cross-browser approach.

Answer (score -1):

Would you be better off using the document object to detect the Enter action? That way you need make no changes to the HTML form tags. You can assign the search function to the button, although if it's hidden I am not sure how the user would click on it, or you could use something like onblur to capture the user tabbing out of the input control.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an attribute "action=javascript:void(0)" as in the example below.

Enter will trigger the same action as clicking on the submit button, but won't reload the page automatically.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form action="javascript:void(0)">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'submitted';"/>
    </form>
    <script>document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'page loaded';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't control the HTML text of the form so this can not be done.

Comment: sure, but with javascript I guess you could control it